# How to Touch up prefinished white trim

Tags: painting, paint

We have white prefinished trim throughout the house, and we've tried to touch up the trim in places where it has seen some damage with an Interior Acrylic Latex paint but the latex paint has started to peel up. I am looking for a recommendation on what steps to take to touch up the trim. What types of paint might adhere better? how might I fix the parts that are pealing? Below is a close up of the trim and you can see where the latex pain is coming up: [image]

I've tried doing an acetone test and a small amount of white paint did come off but not much.
I got a quote from a painter and they said they use a "Urethane Enamel" on trim. Would that work better? Or would any oil based paint work? Do I need to sand it down in the spots I want to touch up? I know for a fact that the quarter rounds are "Pine Primed Quarter Round Moulding" because I purchased them, as for the existing molding I would assume it is something similar.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I am mostly asking for those with knowledge of material choices and steps to touch up finished trim. Do I need to sand first? Do I need to use an oil based paint? Much like the tour you pointed had answers recommending `Use proper sheet-metal screws into the studs. "Self-drilling" screws will save a step, or you can pre-drill the proper size hole for the screws.` I can do my own shopping I just need to know what steps to take to take as well as what materials to use.

Comment: You may want to edit your question a bit, e.g. taking out the Sherwin Williams question and focusing more on types of paint.

Comment: It would also be most helpful to know what kind of material the trim is - anything can be "prefinished", but when the finish comes off, the appropriate new covering and the application technique is based on the underlying material, not the fact that it previously had a finish on it.